# Lightweight selfmade Java MySQL Connection Pooling - would it work?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, connection-pooling

I've been using several connection pooling api's before but I thought its time to do something on my own. Iam currently searching for a very basic MySQL Connection Pooling function on which I can build on. I really would appreciate if you guys could give me a honest opinion!

Here's the code:

```
package temp.jdbc;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MySQL {

    private static final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/beta";
    private static final String username = "root";
    private static final String password = "mypassword";

    private static List<Connection> pool = new ArrayList<Connection>();

    public static void setup() {

        try {

            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                Class.forName(driver);
                Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
                pool.add(connection);
            }

        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    }

    public static void addConnection(Connection connection) {
        pool.add(connection);
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection connection = null;
        if(pool.size() <= 0) return connection;
        connection = pool.get(0); pool.remove(0);
        return connection;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Sincerely,
Gemaken

Comment: At a minimum your connection pool should implement the `javax.sql.DataSource` interface (so the code using the pool doesn't know it's using a pool), though you really shouldn't implement your own.  If you're really set on doing so, look at C3P0 - http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0 - which gets it right

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! I will have a look into that but first, could you please tell me, why everyone is that convinced, that people should use existing Connection Pooling API's?

Comment: In the vast majority of cases rolling-your-own is the wrong thing to do. An API like C3P0 is robust implementation that has been used by 1000s of people, making it very well proven

Comment: There is like at least several major bugs in this little chunk of code. As others suggested you should learn a lot more before you decide to implement your own connection pooling.

Answer (score 0):

There's some major issues with your implementation of a connection pool - connections aren't returned to the pool, no thread-safety, no blocking when all connections are being used, it's static, etc.

Given this, I'll start with the basics.

First, the whole point of any pool is to hold an expensive resource, in this case a [javax.sql.Connection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html), so that it may be reused in the future avoiding the cost of creating that resource again.

With most pools there's a min and max - when created the pool will create the min number of resources and can expand upto the max as the resources are consumed.

When a resource is retrieved from a pool, the retrieving thread should be guaranteed exclusive use of that resource, until the resource is returned to the pool.

Should all resources be being used, any further attempts to obtain a resource should block (with some sort of timeout) until a resource is available.

The use of a pool implies that the application is multi-threaded, so it is also important that the implementation is thread-safe.

As the JDBC API is well defined connection pools typically implement [javax.sql.DataSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) allowing connection pools to be switched in and out as needed.  Given this [javax.sql.Connection.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close--) should be used to return the connection to the pool.